# How to add different model to ModelForm as extra field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

So I'm trying to add an extra field to a ModelForm class in the `__init__` func, so that on the Create/Update class views I could grab this model and create a new model. Since the Model doesn't have this field, how could I add it in the `__init__` func or is there some other way I could add this field?

I've tried overriding `__init__` method to include this field in the ModelForm class, but this still throws me an error that the argument is unexpected

```
class MeterInstallationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MeterInstallation
        fields = METER_INSTALLATION_DEFAULT_FIELDS

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get("instance")
        super(MeterInstallationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if instance:
            #  get tariff info in the form
            # self.fields["tariff"] = instance.tariff
            self.fields["tariff"] = TariffApplication.objects.filter(meter_installation__pk=instance.meter_installation.pk).values_list("tariff", flat=True)

class MeterInstallationCreateView(MeterInstallationsViewMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "meter_installations/meter_installation_create.html"
    fields = (
        "name",
        "meter_type",
        "parent",
        "meter",
        "building",
        "initial_reading",
        "final_reading",
        "active_after",
        "active_until",
        "comment",
    )
    form_class = MeterInstallationForm


meter_installation_create_view = MeterInstallationCreateView.as_view()

class MeterInstallation(ActiveAfterUntilModel, DateTrackedModel, MPTTModel, NamedModel):  # type: ignore
    meter_type = models.ForeignKey(
        MeterType,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name="installations",
        verbose_name=_("Meter Installation type"),
    )
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="children", db_index=True
    )
    meter = models.ForeignKey(
        Meter, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="installations", null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_("Meter")
    )
    building = models.ForeignKey(
        Building,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="meter_installations",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_("Building"),
    )
    places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, related_name="meter_installations", blank=False, verbose_name=_("Places"))
    initial_reading = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, null=False, blank=False, default=0, verbose_name=_("Initial reading")
    )
    final_reading = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True, default=0, verbose_name=_("Final reading")
    )

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ["meter"]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("meter-installations:meter-installation-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        first_lvl_children = self.get_children().filter(level=1)
        for first_lvl_child in first_lvl_children:
            first_lvl_child.parent = None
            first_lvl_child.save()
            for leaf in first_lvl_child.get_children():
                leaf.parent = first_lvl_child
                leaf.save()
            tree_id = first_lvl_child.tree_id

            MeterInstallation.objects.partial_rebuild(tree_id)

        super(MeterInstallation, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"[{self.pk}] type: {self.meter_type_id}, meter: {self.meter_id}"

class Tariff(ActiveAfterUntilModel, NamedModel, DateTrackedModel):
    tariff_type = models.ForeignKey(
        MeterType,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name="tariffs",
        verbose_name=_("Tariff type"),
    )
    building = models.ForeignKey(
        Building, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="tariffs", null=True, blank=False, verbose_name=_("Building")
    )
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True, unique=False, verbose_name=_("Unit name"))
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, null=False, blank=False, default=0.0, verbose_name=_("Unit price")
    )
    VAT = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("VAT"))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "tariff_type", "active_after", "active_until")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("tariffs:tariff-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (
            f"[{self.pk}] "
            f"type: {self.tariff_type_id}, "
            f"building: {self.building_id}, "
            f"price: {self.unit_price}, "
            f"VAT: {self.VAT}, "
            f"active_until: {self.active_until}"
        )

class TariffApplication(ActiveAfterUntilModel, DateTrackedModel):  # type: ignore
    tariff = models.ForeignKey(
        Tariff,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name="tariff_applications",
        verbose_name=_("Tariff Applications"),
    )
    meter_installation = models.ForeignKey(
        "MeterInstallation",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name="tariff_applications",
        verbose_name=_("Meter Installation"),
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"[{self.pk}] tariff: {self.tariff_id}, meter installation: {self.meter_installation_id}"
```

I would love to know how to make this work, so that in my CreateView I could start creating a third model by the given Tariff

Comment: Please show your models.

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) so that you can select a `tariff` on the form.

```
class MeterInstallationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MeterInstallation
        fields = METER_INSTALLATION_DEFAULT_FIELDS

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MeterInstallationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["tariff"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tariff.objects.all())
```

Then in your `form_valid()` method, you can retrieve the `tariff` from `cleaned_data` and create the related `TariffApplication`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save()
    TariffApplication.objects.create(tariff=form.cleaned_data['tariff'], meter_installation=instance)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

You may need to change the queryset if you need to filter the list of available tariffs. In your original question, I don't think it makes sense to have `if instance` in the form's `__init__` method, because an instance won't be passed to the form for a `CreateView`.

Comment: Well, now my server at least is running so that is good, but the one thing that I don't get is that if I initialize the form with overriden `__init__` , I should see `tariff` field in the form where I could choose the Tariff from the query, but now I dont see that + my MeterInstallationMPTTAdmin is crashing because it uses the same Form => `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'queryset'`

Comment: There was a typo in my code - the first argument to `ModelChoiceField` is the queryset.

Comment: As I said in the answer above, `CreateView` does not pass an instance to the form, so if you create the model choice field inside `if instance:` then that line is not going to run for your create view.

Comment: I've removed that line, as you said and left that `__init__` from your comment, but the form still doesn't render the form with `tariff` field where I should choose from that `self.fields["tariff"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tariff.objects.all())`

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then. To debug, I would try adding some logs or `print()`s to the form's `__init__` method to make sure it is running, and look at how you are rending the form in the template.

Comment: I will try to debug/print this issue now, your help was really solid, once I will solve this I will mark this as complete, THANKS A LOT!:)

Comment: All I needed is to change fields to form_class in the view, thanks a LOT!:)

Comment: Glad you got it working. In your question you already had `form_class = MeterInstallationForm`. I though that specifying `fields` as well as `form_class` was unnecessary, but I didn't think it would stop it from displaying the `tariff` field.

Comment: I wasn't able to use fields and form_class together, had an error, so just by specifying form_class made it work, thanks again, you good person!:)

Answer (score 1):

You can include extra field in your ModelForm and set that in your view such as:

```py
# forms.py
class MeterInstallationForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = MeterInstallation
        fields = METER_INSTALLATION_DEFAULT_FIELDS + ('tariff',)
```

```py
# views.py
class MeterInstallationCreateView(MeterInstallationsViewMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "meter_installations/meter_installation_create.html"
    fields = (
        "name",
        "meter_type",
        "parent",
        "meter",
        "building",
        "initial_reading",
        "final_reading",
        "active_after",
        "active_until",
        "comment",
    )
    form_class = MeterInstallationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.tariff = forms.TariffApplication(form.data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I have a class based view, so If I just add a template_class in the CreateView this still throws me an error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (tariff) specified for MeterInstallation`

Comment: I need to somehow include this field before accessing my `CreateView`

Comment: Can you share your view as well? You can add this implementation in the create method of your view as well.

Comment: Please add that into your question :)

Comment: this still throws the same error, I need to grab `Tariff` in this `MeterInstallation` CreateView so that I could create that TariffApplication model and assign it Tariff and MeterInstallation